# How to display a large list with checkboxes inside

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on some webapp where i have a table which is filled with some data and to select which data should be displayed i use filters. 
These filters are `<div>` elemtens which contain one `<div>` per filter option like so:

```
<div id="selectedFilter">
  <div>
    <input id="selectedFilter1" type="checkbox" name="selectedFilter" multiple="true" value="1" checked="true">
    <label for="selectedFilter1" title="Option1">Option1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="selectedFilter2" type="checkbox" name="selectedFilter" multiple="true" value="2" checked="true">
    <label for="selectedFilter2" title="Option2">Option2</label>
  </div>
<div>
```

The html code for the options (the whole `<div>` with `<label>` and `<input>` )  is generated in my java backend and gets transferred to the site like this:

```
$.post("filter", result, function(data) {
  $("#selectedFilter").html(data);
});
```

**Now my problem:**

The amount of filters gets sometimes really high (e.g. 800 rows) and there are two more filters on the page with about the same amount of options. With such a load of data the browser begins to hang and becomes unresponsive.

To fix this i tried using virtual scrolling since this seems to be the most reasonable way to keep the browsercache on a good level. But this clears the checkboxes, if i render the whole div again. 
On top of that i need to know which checkboxes are checked even if they are not in the viewport because the filters are influencing each others possible options in a cascading manner (*Filter1* influences *Filter2* influences *Filter3*). If one filter changes (something gets selected) the subsequent one (or two) gets cleared and requests new data from the java backend.

**Question:**
Is there maybe a js-library which supports the virtual scrolling but manages the checkboxes by itself so i can extract just the checked ones? Something like this.

I might try to save which chechbox was selected but i fear that the virtualisation of the scrolling might be very slow if there is a matching of the displayed options whether they are checked or not in every single scroll.

Does anybody have suggestions or experiences?

Comment: maybe use angular and pagination on items?:)

Comment: Are you sure, you need to show all 800 rows to all the people on the site? Couldn't you just load all depending filters if they are active?

Comment: @vivid I'll look into it ;)

Comment: @Wavemaster the users sees all rows of every filter just as the page loads then he can filter what he needs. Just the first filter always has all elements. But if i activate them one after another the browser will become unresponsive as the lowest hierarchical tier so i would gain nothing. Or am i misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you are having 800 filters , do you really think any user gonna see all those 800 or more filters together. The best thing is to categories your filters and then load them on click of category.

Virtual Scrolling is good idea. You need to append filter data as .html() is overriding your previous content.

```
 $("#selectedFilter").append(data);
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong: I have 800 rows in 3 filters and these 3 filters are something like categories. You can think of them as a hierarchy which goes from general to more detailed.

e.g.: Carbrands(Filter 1) -> Carmodel(Filter2) -> Series of a Carmodel(Filter3)

Comment: ok fine :)

for rendering on scrolling you need to append data.